# UITableViewCell autolayout

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I have a problem with autolayout. I have a `UITableViewCell` and a view inside. I want this view to be smaller than the cell so I've added constraints:

- Vertical space (10) top
- Vertical space (10) bottom
- Horizontal space (10) leading space
- Horizontal space (10) trailing space

When tableView appears the cell is displayed good, but then if I scroll down the tableView and scroll back up, the View in the cell is resized and now takes full space in the cell.

Correct cell:
[image]

Incorrect cell (after scroll)
[image]

I've already searched for this, but couldn't find anything similar.
I think this person had the same problem, but there's no answer:
[Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854485/auto-layout-of-custom-programmatic-uitableviewcell-fails-upon-scrolling)

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: please add your relevant code here :)

Comment: Are you loading the cell from a nib or storyboard, or are you creating it entirely in code?  Are you using a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: @robmayoff I am using a xib for this cell and load it from xib. I also use a custom subclass of UITableViewCell for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally found the answer to my question [here](http://www.lextech.com/2013/01/uitableviewcell-editing-with-autolayout/). In my custom UITableViewCell class I've done like this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    for (NSLayoutConstraint *cellConstraint in self.constraints)
    {
        [self removeConstraint:cellConstraint];

        id firstItem = cellConstraint.firstItem == self ? self.contentView : cellConstraint.firstItem;
        id seccondItem = cellConstraint.secondItem == self ? self.contentView : cellConstraint.secondItem;

        NSLayoutConstraint* contentViewConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:firstItem
                                                                                 attribute:cellConstraint.firstAttribute
                                                                                 relatedBy:cellConstraint.relation
                                                                                    toItem:seccondItem
                                                                                 attribute:cellConstraint.secondAttribute
                                                                                multiplier:cellConstraint.multiplier
                                                                                  constant:cellConstraint.constant];

        [self.contentView addConstraint:contentViewConstraint];
    }
}
```

I guess the content view resizes its content or something similar. If there's an easier explanation to this and more easy way of doing so, I'm still waiting for other answers. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Constraints created on a `UITableViewCell` in a xib (or storyboard) connect directly to the cell, rather than to its `contentView` subview.  But they need to be connected to the `contentView` for proper layout.  That's why your fix works.  I don't know if it's a bug in Xcode or a bug in UIKit.

Comment: @robmayoff - I believe it is an IB/XCode bug, not UIKit.  If you examine the storyboard XML emitted by XCode 4.6 it's clear that constraints are added to the cell vs the contentView for subviews of the contentView.  In builds of XCode later than 4.6 this is corrected and constraints belong to the contentView.

Answer (score 1):

<del>I had this same problem today using Xcode 5 and storyboards. Initially, my custom table view cells would appear correctly, but as I scrolled through the table view and the cells were reused, the layout would mess up. The fix was to call `setNeedsLayout` like so:</del>

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SettingTableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Setting" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [tableViewCell.contentView setNeedsLayout];

    return tableViewCell;
}
```

**The REAL problem:**

I named my label outlet `textLabel`, which is the same name as UITableViewCell's built-in label property. This was causing all kinds of weirdness. As soon as I changed the outlet property name to a unique name, my layout issues were solved.

Comment: I figured that all cells should have a view inside it, connect this view as cells content view, and only then add content inside, like uilabels and other stuff. This way seems to get rid of all the problems.

Comment: I had the same problem with "imageView". Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This problem is generated because Your `UITableView` Reuse Cell instant of create new one.
I give you some suggestion that may be helpful for you.

1)   add `UIView` in between

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   
  {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        /// Your code;
    }
 return cell;

}
```

1) Add Your UIView to `cell.contentView.`

**EDITED:**

Before You follow my Edited Answer i want to tell you that following code is bad for memory management because it will create new cell for each rows of `UITableView`, so be careful for it.

But it is better for if `UITableView` Have Limited row about (50-100 may be ) os use following code if is it suitable for you.

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. I don't really understand why this is happening, this doesn't happen in simple uiview, just in tableviewcell. Maybe i need to set [view setNeedsLayout] or something like that, for the autolayout constraints to work in tableview cell?

Comment: thanks again for your help, but it would be very slow and inefficient. I would like to do it the proper way :)

Comment: This is a serious abuse of the cell reuse pattern in UITableView and should definitely be avoided, as it will lead to greater memory usage.